# Input type not validate Validation in AngularJs Html

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4, angularjs-ng-model

In Angularjs form validation of Email-Id and Password is not working. Please check below code snippet.

```
    <div class="field_w3ls">
        <div class="field-group">                     
            <input type="text" name="email"  placeholder="Email" id="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email"  ng-pattern="/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/" required />
            <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
            <span ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$error.required" class="help-block">Email is required</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field_w3ls"> 
        <div class="field-group">                       
            <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" required />
            <span toggle="password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>       
        </div>
    </div>
```

But when we remove the **ng-model** Its working fine. I am new in AngularJs.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

provide novalidate in form tag and please check with this code

```
    <form name="form" novalidate>
    <div class="field_w3ls">
            <div class="field-group">                     
                <input type="text" name="email"  placeholder="Email" id="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email"  ng-pattern="/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/" required/>     
                <span ng-if="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$invalid" class="help-block">
                  <span ng-show="form.email.$error.required">Email is required</span>
                  <span ng-show="form.email.$error.pattern">Invalid email</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="field_w3ls"> 
            <div class="field-group">                       
                <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" required />
                <span toggle="password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>             
<span ng-if="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$invalid" class="help-block">
               <span ng-show="form.password.$error.required">password is required
</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

** In controller give **

```
$scope.email = '';
$scope.password = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Name your form like `name="loginForm"`, and check for `$invalid` in the form email field, as you want to validate for required and pattern.

```
<form name="loginForm" novalidate>
    <div class="field_w3ls">
        <div class="field-group">                     
            <input type="text" name="email"  placeholder="Email" id="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email"  ng-pattern="/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/" required />
            <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
            <span ng-show="loginForm.email.$dirty && loginForm.email.$invalid" class="help-block">Email is required</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field_w3ls"> 
        <div class="field-group">                       
            <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" required />
            <span toggle="password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>       
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, For your valuable suggestions  !!